# Dynamic Table using white-space: nowrap

Tags: html, css

I'd like to build a table with two columns (and one row) and specific width. The left cell will contain a text that should be single-line and auto-ellipsis. The right cell should have dynamic content which automagically grows the right cell's width and therefore shrinks the left cell's width.

The div/css solution with `display: table/table-cell` is bad, since it makes both cells 50% wide.

[div fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaseNewmark/Xk4Rh)

The raw-table/css solution is also bad, since `white-space: nowrap` (needed for the `text-overflow`) breaks the tables automatic layout mechanism and even grows it over its original width.

[table fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaseNewmark/Xk4Rh/1/)

Can somebody solve the mysterical mystery?
BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware [this is the closest you'll get](http://jsfiddle.net/L8S9L/2/), the requirements you list unfortunately wont resolve - you will need to set a width on at least one of the containers, or resort to using some JS so the point at which to stop expanding is known to them.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <span>Something quite long that should exceed the table cell.</span> 
   <span>here is some moreSomething quite long that should exceed the table cell.Something quite long that should exceed the table cell.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
span{
    padding 0 20;
    margin:0;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
span:first-child{
     white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
span:last-child{
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: This is what I expected, since I already check so many alternatives. I was just hoping for some magic from the css pros ;-). Thanks anyway.